# I get an error when sending an email in a new window

Tags: outlook, dialog, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins, new-window

I'm creating an add-in on Outlook on the Web, and I'm seeing unexpected behavior when I test it.

Details are described below.

1. Click "New message" on the Outlook on the web.
2. Click "Open in new window".
3. Wait about 10 minutes on the "new window".
4. Compose an email. and Click the "Send" button.
5. The process does not proceed and I cannot send an email.
6. After about 3 minutes, the following error message is displayed.
7. "We're sorry, we couldn't access "add-in Name". Make sure you have a network connection. If the problem continues, please try again later."

Probability and time of occurrence are irregular.

Please tell me how to solve this problem.

[2022.04.08]

index.js

```
/*
 * Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved. Licensed under the MIT license.
 * See LICENSE in the project root for license information.
 */

var mailboxItem;

Office.initialize = function (reason) {
    mailboxItem = Office.context.mailbox.item;
}

// Entry point for Contoso Message Body Checker add-in before send is allowed.
// <param name="event">MessageSend event is automatically passed by BlockOnSend code to the function specified in the manifest.</param>
function validateBody(event) {
  Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(
  "https://localhost:3000/index.html",
    {
      height: 65,
      width: 40,
      displayInIframe: true,
      asyncContext: event,
    },
      (asyncResult) => {
        asyncResult.value.addEventHandler(Office.EventType.DialogEventReceived,
        (processMessage) => {
          asyncResult.value.close()
          asyncResult.asyncContext.completed({ allowEvent: false })
        }
      )
    }
  )
}
```

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/office.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    test
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How does your manifest look like? Are you able to reproduce the issue with a newly created empty add-in?

Comment: Does your outlook add-in manifest contain "On-Send" event? If On send event is present in the manifest then, the mail send gets blocked if the on send event is not found or if the on send event blocks the send.
Read more about it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/outlook-on-send-addins?tabs=classic

Comment: Dear Eugene Astafiev. It does not occur when I try it with the following sample project.  https://github.com/OfficeDev/Outlook-Add-in-On-Send/blob/master/outlook-add-in-on-send/Contoso%20Message%20Body%20Checker.xml/ I think that it does not occur because the sample project does not use "displayDialogAsync".

Comment: Dear Outlook Add-ins Team - MSFT. Yes, I am using "On-Send" event. There are also new discoveries. It always happens when you follow the steps below. 1) Click "New message" on the Outlook on the web. 2) Click "Open in new window". 3) Switch web browser tabs. 4)Click the "Send" button.

Comment: (1) Can you please share a video when this problem occurs? (2) Can you also please share your manifest so that we can install your addin and try this in our test accounts (I am assuming addin is hosted publicly and we can also access it)?

Comment: sorry. I can't share files because it's my product. By the way, there was another new discovery. When I tried my product to the minimum size, I got different results. 
The dialog is displayed after 10 seconds.Why is this?
I share this result on video and source code. add the source code to "Asked". video→ https://drive.google.com/file/d/10skK4dEjqUr9hVb69IRpGPv6BjbfrIK-/view

Comment: Thanks for sharing the video. (1) Are you saying that when we try to send "2nd time", Dialog opens after 10 seconds? (2) Can you please create a sample addin where this problem is reproducible and share manifest/code with us?

Comment: (1) No. Occurs whenever you open a new window and switch tabs.

(2)Sorry. I can't share the add-in because I don't have a place to publish it.

Can I try the following steps instead?

1) Download the official sample.
　https://github.com/OfficeDev/Outlook-Add-in-On-Send

2) Rewrite the contents of the "app.js" file to the source code of "index.js" that you shared the other day.

3) Run the "yarn start" command in your local environment.

4) Install the add-in with the manifest file.

Comment: Thanks for reporting this issue regarding delay in launching dialog . It has been put on our backlog. We unfortunately have no timelines to share at this point

Comment: Dear Outlook Add-ins Team - MSFT. Thank you as always.
Is it possible to repair it immediately or will it take time?
I need to explain the situation to customers using this product.

Comment: Hi,
Could you give me an update on the situation?
and Can you share the backlog URL?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you specified the `ItemSend` event in the manifest file and your add-in can't be located or reached. Or the event handler specified in the manifest isn't publicly available.